Convert PCAP to CSV
I have 82 .pcap files and I need to convert all of them into .csv format. Is there any way that I can convert all of the files together?
The way I could find was using WireShark but using that I’ll need to convert each file one by one which is an extremely tedious task.

Use tcpdump to read the pcap files and output the data in TSV
tcpdump -qns 0 -r inputFILE.pcap | awk -f pcapToTSV.awk > outputFILE.tsv
Convert TSV to CSV using csvformat
csvformat -t outputFILE.tsv > outputFILE.csv
